# Reputation not adding up?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation

According to the achievements tab as of right now I have gained 20 points and lost 2, yet my reputation on physics stackexchange shows as 19 and here it shows as 21.

Is this a glitch?

EDIT: after I posted this my reputation here now shows as 19.

EDIT2: In retrospect I should have asked two questions: the first one about the inconsistency between sites which has been answered, and another one about the minor inconsistency between what I see and what the site shows (19 shown, but adds up to 18), which still appears to be a bug.

Comment: Wait a while Things are cached and update on different schedules...

Comment: Reputation is one-based, not zero-based. You start off with one rep. point. Add 20 and subtract 2, and you end up with 19.